# Issue with my regular expression?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to locate the number of matches in a relative path for directory up references ("`..\`"). So I have the following pattern : "`(\.\.\\)`", which works as expected for the path "`..\..\a\b`" where it will give me 2 successful groups ("`..\`"), but when I try the path "`..\a\b`" it will also return 2 when it should return 1. I tried this in a reg ex tool such as Expresso and it seems to work as expected in there but not in .net, any ideas?

Comment: According to http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx, your regex works in NET. Something else must be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm getting the correct answer, try the following:

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Matches(@"..\..\a\b", @"(\.\.\\)").Count); //2
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Matches(@"..\a\b", @"(\.\.\\)").Count); //1
```

Did you escape or use literal strings for the `\` in .NET?

Comment: Thanks so obviously my usage of it must be wrong in code since yours confirms Expresso's results. Will investigate.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the issue was related to me using Match instead Matches which returns a collection.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

> `(\.\.\\)`

The dots (`.`) were matching any character, not the literal value. To match the literal value you must escape them with a leading backslash.

Comment: That's what I have currently, but slashes got removed when I submitted the question. I have edited the post to now include them.

Answer (score 0):

Since Expresso runs on .net, your statement "I tried this in a reg ex tool such as Expresso and it seems to work as expected in there but not in .net" doesn't seem to make a lot of sense.
What this suggests me is that it's not the regular expression which is the problem, but your usage of it.
Have a close look at the Regex method you're using to collect results and how you process those results, that might be where the problem lies.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think the posts above under stood the question ok ,will following their suggestions and report back.

Comment: Hey, look at that, I was right!  You were using Match instead of Matches, so it was a usage problem.  Good to know you got it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you escape the backslahes to escape the dots in your Regex? I.e. `"\\.\\.\\\\"` or `@"\.\.\\"`?

You could always not use Regex for this task and use

```
Int32 count = url.Split(new string[] { "\\" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                 .Where(s => s == "..")
                 .Count();
```

instead. =)